# Optimizing MySQL query using GROUP BY on time functions

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT location, step, COUNT(*), AVG(foo), YEAR(start), MONTH(start), DAY(start)
FROM table WHERE jobid = 'xxx' AND start BETWEEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-08'
GROUP BY location, step, YEAR(start), MONTH(start), DAY(start)
```

Originally I had indexes on individual columns, such as *jobid* and *start*, but quickly realized that MySQL only really honors one index per table in a select. As such, it would use the *jobid* index and then do a pretty large scan to filter out by the *start* range.

Adding an index on (*jobid*, *start*) helped quite a bit, but the GROUP BY is still causing performance issues. I've read the [docs on GROUP BY optimizations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) and understand that in order to benefit from these optimizations I need an index that contains (*location*, *step*, *start*), but I still have two open questions:

1. Will the group by optimizations even work with the time functions (YEAR, MONTH, DAY, etc)? Or am I going to have to store these values as separate columns? The reason I like doing the functions is that it means I can control the time zone on a per-connection basis and get back results tailored to the end-users time zone. If I have to pre-store the year, month, and day, I'll do it via UTC and then all my users will just get reports in UTC.
2. Even if I can solve issue #1, can I even do this? The index (*jobid*, *start*) helped with the WHERE clause, but the GROUP BY needs a different index to be optimized (*location*, *step*, *start*) or, depending on the answer to #1, (*location*, *step*, *year*, *month*, *day*). But the problem is that those two indexes don't share a common left-hand set of columns, so I don't believe my WHERE and GROUP by can be compatible such that the same index gets used. So my question is: am I just hosed here?

Any other thoughts on how to achieve this would be helpful. And, just to preempt a few questions/comments that might come up:

1. Yes, this is a time-series data set.
2. Yes, it would benefit from something like [RRDtool](http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool/), but doing so would cause me to loose doing timezone-specific results.
3. Yes, pre-calculating rollups would probably be a good idea, but I don't need *awesome* performance and so I'm OK with *good* performance if it lets me customize the results for each user's timezone.

With the above said, if anyone has any design suggestions on how to do something like rollups or round-robin databases and still get timezone-specific results, I'm all ears!

---

*Update*: as requested, here is some more info:

show indexes from  output:

```
step    0   PRIMARY 1   step_id A   16  NULL    NULL        BTREE   
step    1   start   1   start   A   16  NULL    NULL        BTREE   
step    1   step    1   step    A   2   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
step    1   foo 1   foo A   16  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE   
step    1   location    1   location    A   2   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE   
step    1   jobid   1   jobid   A   2   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
```

show create table  output:

```
CREATE TABLE `step` (
  `start` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `step` smallint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `step_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobid` varchar(37) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`step_id`),
  KEY `start_time` (`start`),
  KEY `step` (`step`),
  KEY `location` (`location`),
  KEY `job_id` (`jobid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=240 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: can you post the following info pls: show indexes from <tablename> and show create table <tablename> - thx

Comment: @Scrum - the result set is not huge, but it is growing. We have many databases (one for each customer) ranging from 10K to ~10M records depending on customer usage.

Comment: after the grouping, how many rows are returned? how many different combination are there of location, step?

Comment: @Scrum - there are a fixed number of 7 locations and usually no more than 10-15 unique step values. A typical query is trying to return the unique location + step results for each day over a seven day period. So that would be 7 days x 7 locations x 10 steps = 490 rows returned after grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a single composite index on `jobid, start, location, step`

then group by that order first, and sort it:

```
SELECT location, step, COUNT(*), AVG(foo), YEAR(start), MONTH(start), DAY(start)
FROM table WHERE jobid = 'xxx' AND start BETWEEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-08'
GROUP BY YEAR(start), MONTH(start), DAY(start), location, step
ORDER BY location, step, YEAR(start), MONTH(start), DAY(start)
```

UPDATE

Looks like MySql cannot use the index when the YEAR,MONTH and DAY functions are used. since

1. After removing the start from the WHERE clause, the explain still shows `using filesort`
2. Adding 3 columns: `y = YEAR(start), m = MONTH(start), d=DAY(start)`, creating a index on `jobid, y, m, d, location, step` and updating the `WHERE ... AND y = 2010 AND m = 12 AND d BETWEEN 1 AND 08` does remove the `using temporary using filesort`.

keeping 3 extra column seems like a bad idea, since the performance difference between the GROUP BY shouldn't matter that much if it uses temporary or not.

Comment: Ordering is applied **after** groupping. So no reason to add `location` after `start`. Also, is I pointed, no composite index parts will be used after range type condition.

Comment: I added this index on a table with 200K entries and the explain plan looks the same for this query and for my original query. Does that mean they are equal, or are there other optimizations not described in the explain plan?

Comment: @Patrick whats if you remove the AVG(Foo) column? (since Foo was not in your explain table output in your question, i overlooked it)

Comment: @Scrum - Same explain plan: uses the new index, type "range", 17970 rows, and 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort' extras. The actual number of returned rows is 98 (7 locations, 2 steps, 7 days).

Comment: @zerkms you are incorrect, since removing the start range from the WHERE clause doesn't help.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: if that doesn't help - that doesn't mean that **i'm incorrect**, it does mean, that in this particular case optimizer cannot optimize query, or table need to be `OPTIMIZE` or `ANALYZE`, or ... So, sir, be polite next time, saying someone is incorrect.

Comment: @zerkms you are incorrect in that composite index **can** be used for a range filter and group by. as shown by adding 3 columns for day month and year and filtering by **range**

Comment: @Scrum - so not sure where we ended up. Are you suggesting that it is impossible to have an optimized group by that uses the time functions? That the only way to optimize this query further is to have separate columns for each year/month/day?

Comment: @Partick yup as far as i know. what is the selectivity of the `jobid` index?

Comment: @Scrum not sure what you're asking (I'm a bit of a noob in this area), but there are usually no more than 100 unique job IDs

Comment: @Partick Index selectivity = Rows / Rows for each jobid. in your case for 10M rows and 100 job IDs - depending on the job ID - your selectivity = 1% or ~100k rows. if your start range is large, and the start range filter will return less rows, try putting `start` as the first column in the index before `jobid`

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: where I said that "composite index can be used for a range filter and group by"? Please, can you give a reference to my words?

Comment: @zerkms you stated: "Since you're using range condition in WHERE - no indexes will be used for `GROUP BY`. read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: oops, silly me :-( sorry. need to re-read whole optimization chapter

Comment: @zerkms np, i didn't mean to be rude in any way. just sharing my opinion.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: yes, that was my mistake that i started this discussion before reading that chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead doing this

```
GROUP BY location, step, YEAR(start), MONTH(start), DAY(start)
ORDER BY location, step, YEAR(start), MONTH(start), DAY(start)
```

try

```
GROUP BY location, step, date_format(start, '%Y%m%d')
ORDER BY location, step, date_format(start, '%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: I've considered using date_format, but I don't really have any good reasons why it would change things considerably. Can you tell me why you think this would help?

Comment: what you did will use 3 functions on `start`, this approach only using one function and return same result

Comment: I don't believe the function calls are my main performance bottleneck. What I'm trying to accomplish is to optimize the group by such that it uses only the index and doesn't need to do a temporary table with a much larger data set.

Comment: group by 5 fields compare to 3 fields, what give you better boost? beside the index, you can consider to have a column `start_date date`, which is the derived of date from column start, and change the range to `IN`, build composite index on `jobid,start,location,step` like what @zerkms suggest

Answer (score 0):

> and understand that in order to benefit from these optimizations I need an index that contains (location, step, start)

Nope. You could create composite index `jobid + start + location + step` and it **would** help, if there were no `BETWEEN`. Since you're using range condition in `WHERE` - no indexes will be used for `GROUP BY` and the only and the best thing you can do for this query is just `jobid + start` index.

The best solution, imho, is to decompose this table to some pre-calculated form. For example: to aggregate data by scheduler hourly.

Comment: Two follow-up questions: 1) would using > and < in lieu of BETWEEN help? I doubt it but just wanted to double check. And 2) When I add the index you suggested I don't see a change in the explain plain. Should I or are there some types of optimizations that won't show there?

Comment: @patrick 1) no and 2) since you are filtering the star using a range, as zerkms stated, it wont help

Comment: @Scrum - not sure what "since you are filtering the star using a range" means :(

Comment: @patrick since you are filtering the "start" column with a range of values, it cannot use that index for grouping

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance this may select faster if location and step are integer foreign 
keys into other tables just having name & integer id.

First, the query would be groupped on integer data which will compare a lot faster.
Second, there's a chance DB engine may automatically index these numbers.

I'd also consider to offload jobid into a separate table in case the value repeats.